# Service Unavailable HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable. Application pools are stopped

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, application-pool, http-status-code-503

I'm running Windows 8 with IIS8.0

I'm receiving this error when I open a browser to my local site instance:
Service Unavailable
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

After I receive the error, the applicationpools ASP.NET v4.0 and .NET v4.5 are stopped.

After inspection of the IIS eventlogs I see this:
WARNING: Unable to find schema for config section 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment'. This section will be ignored.
WARNING: Unable to find schema for config section 'system.serviceModel/behaviors'. This section will be ignored.
WARNING: Unable to find schema for config section 'system.web.extensions/scripting/webServices/jsonSerialization'. This section will be ignored.
ERROR: An error has occurred: Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'key' set to 'DefaultLanguage'

For all above events the following attributes are shown:
USER: MARK-PC\Mark
SOURCE: IIS-Configuration

I checked C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
But can't find an entry 'DefaultLanguage' there.

My web.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
            <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>




<appSettings>
    <clear/>
    <add key="DefaultLanguage" value="nl" />
...
```

I also find the following line in the Event Viewer (local)\Windows Logs\Application:
"The Module DLL C:\WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv\compstat.dll failed to load.  The data is the error."

I checked and there's no compstat.dll file in the \inetsrv folder. Apparently this is for static compression, but don't know if I have enabled this or how to get the file installed!

I then checked what worker processes are started (followed instructions here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735182(v=WS.10).aspx):
- Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Administrative Tools.
- Right-click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager and select Run as administrator.
- In the Connections pane, select the computer name.
- In Features View, under the Feature Name column heading, double-click the Worker Processes management feature. A list of currently active application pools and worker processes will appear.
- The State column for the worker process will indicate Running if the worker process is running.

I don't see any running processes here.

What can I do about the above?

Comment: How did you solve this issue? I am having the same problem.